# How to disable/delete all breakpoint in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Is there a way to disable all breakpoints in Qt Creator? 
If there is not, Is there a way to delete all breakpoints?
My Qt version is 4.7 and my OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the debugger pane at the bottom of the IDE. In the bottom right corner, there will be a breakpoint tab. Click this and you should see all breakpoints displayed. Now you can `CTRL + A` and right click and delete all breakpoints.

([ref](http://qtcreator.blogspot.com/2009/07/delete-all-breakpoints.html?showComment=1303920086876#c3203469405547413384).)

[image: disable-breakpoint.png]

Comment: You can also enable/disable them this way. Unfortunately, cuirrently not by single button (see [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/102941/dis-enable-all-breakpoints)).